# Frank-Wolfe theorem: why the polyhedral set must be convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

The theorem states that a  lower bounded quadratic function attains its infimum on a convex polyhedral set. My question is why does the set must be convex?

I've been trying to understand the analytical proof from Blum and Oettli and I can't see where the convexity is involved.

Thank you!

Comment: Where did you see the theorem is stated with the "convex" term? The polyhedral set defined in the paper is implicitly convex by itself because it's an intersection of convex sets.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought so, but I wasn't quite sure.